# Можно ли сказать "став вращаться"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, деепричастный-оборот

*Даже войдя в круг столичной интеллигенции, **став вращаться** в кругах ученых...*

Не могу сообразить, можно ли сказать "став вращаться"?
То, что надо заменить один из "кругов", — понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так **нельзя** сказать ни в прямом, ни в переносном смысле: деепричастие "**став**" (в отличие от порождающего его глагола в прошедшем или будущем времени) *не сочетается с глаголами* (только с существительными и прилагательными, характеризуя переход в *статичное состояние*, но не действие). Попытку дать этой несочетаемости *формальное* объяснение делала "Грамота" ( http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82&start=45 ) , но меня приведённые там рассуждения не убедили.

О двигателе можно сказать "**завращавшись**", "**начав вращаться**". Здесь (в переносном смысле) можно напр. "**уже вращаясь**".

**P.S.** Прямая *причина* несочетаемости, на мой взгляд, заключается в том, что в нормативном глагольном сочетании "**стал (станет) вращаться**" глагол "стать" используется в функции *вспомогательного* (*модифицирует время*, подобно глаголу "быть"), со значением перехода к действию основного глагола (которое с этого момента продолжается или повторяется многократно). Это связано с ограничениями: такое сочетание *не* преобразуется в *деепричастную* конструкцию и не удаётся употребить в нём вспомогательный глагол в *инфинитиве* или в *настоящем* времени. Ближаюшую аналогию таким ограничениям можно увидеть в сочетаниях с глаголом "быть", используемым для образования будущего времени. Очевидно, что сочетание "будет вращаться" (как и "станет вращаться") нельзя преобразовать в инфинитив ("быть вращаться" или "стать вращаться" лишено смысла) или в деепричастную конструкцию с сохранением формы основного глагола ("будучи вращаться" или "став вращаться"), можно только употребить деепричастие с причастием: "будучи вращающимся", "став вращающимся".

Answer (score 1):

"Став вращаться" — так нельзя говорить; правильно было бы сказать или **стал вращаться**, или **вращался**, или **вращаясь**.

Вот *возможные* варианты предложения ( второй "круг" заменяем на "среду"):
Даже войдя в круг столичной интеллигенции, вращаясь в среде ученых, он умудрился...
Она, даже войдя в круг столичной интеллигенции и вращаясь в среде ученых, не утратила...

Деепричастный оборот — это деепричастие с зависимыми словами.
В предложении деепричастный оборот всегда выполняет функцию обстоятельства.
Так как деепричастие обозначает дополнительное действие, **деепричастный оборот всегда относится к глаголу** (чаще всего — к глаголу-сказуемому).
[**Построение предложения с деепричастным оборотом**](https://lampa.io/p/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-00000000300b9ce9c460c1aed44d3056)

Конструкция ***деепричастие + глагол*** (внутри оборота) невозможна.
Примеры использования деепричастия "став":

*Лишь однажды споткнулся

И упал с небосвода,

Потеряв свои крылья,

Свет души и свободу.

**Став** изломанной **тенью**

Себя прежнего, блеклым

**Став** своим **отражением**,

Переполненным болью...*
***Став рабом*** притяжения,
Подружиться с землею,
Но смотреть только в небо
С затаенной тоскою.
[**М. Смирнов. Падший**](https://mybook.ru/author/mihail-smirnov/nechayannye-mysli/read/?page=2)

*Он поднялся, прошелся по комнате и, став передо мной, сказал...*
Ги де Мопассан. Завещание

Answer (score 1):

***Став вращаться*** ― это неправильно, но об этом уже сказано, осталось только **объяснить почему.**

Сравним два сочетания: ***начал вращать и стал вращаться***. Значение практически одинаковое, вот только у глагола ***начать*** (в функции фазового глагола в составном глагольном сказуемом) это основное значение, а у многозначного глагола ***стать*** оно периферийное, одно из многих.

В словаре у глагола ***стать*** можно выделить два обобщенных смысла: (1) занять положение, (2) перейти в состояние.

Ко второму значению относятся оба следующих примера:  **стал (начал) учиться, стал инженером.** Но в составном именном сказуемом ***стал*** ―  основной глагол-связка, а в составном глагольном сказуемом его легко заменить ― ***начал учиться.***

**В деепричастных оборотах нормативность этих  сочетаний расходится**: мы говорим: ***став инженером,*** но не говорим: ***став учиться***.

**Так в грамматике или семантике тут дело?** Мне думается, что **грамматика здесь ни при чем**, судя по тому, что существует аналогичное сочетание **начав вращаться**, обозначающее то же самое действие. Всё дело в лексике этих двух глаголов (*начать* и *стать*).

Примеры

**Начав вращаться,** двигатель уже не останавливается (если он вечный). В прямом значении так можно сказать.

Даже войдя в круг столичной интеллигенции, ***начав вращаться*** в кругах ученых...

А вот в составе устойчивого оборота деепричастная форма выглядит не лучшим образом, то же содержание желательно выразить как-то иначе, например:

**Даже войдя в круг столичной интеллигенции, став известным среди ученых..**